# if (TRUE) condition before a function definition

Tags: r

I have some R code that has `if (TRUE)` before a function begins. What is the purpose of that conditional statement?

```
if (TRUE) {
    f <- function(x, y) {
        z <- x + y
        z
    }
    f(2, 3)
}
```

Comment: `if(FALSE)` will not run ~

Comment: It really has no purpose in the given context.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes people will wrap blocks of code `...` in `if (FALSE){ ... }` if they want to execute a whole script in one shot but are still working on the stuff in `...`. So seems plausible that whoever wrote it was satisfied enough with `...` that they want it to be executed whenever they source the script. (changing `FALSE` to `TRUE` is basically the same thing as just deleting the conditional)

Just a guess but that could explain it!

Comment: One can just comment out the whole block though.

Comment: Depending on the editor commenting out a block isn't always easy